# Injecting a String property with @InjectMocks

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mockito

I have a Spring MVC `@Controller` with this constructor:

```
@Autowired
public AbcController(XyzService xyzService, @Value("${my.property}") String myProperty) {/*...*/}
```

I want to write a standalone unit test for this Controller:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AbcControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private XyzService mockXyzService;

    private String myProperty = "my property value";

    @InjectMocks
    private AbcController controllerUnderTest;

    /* tests */
}
```

Is there any way to get `@InjectMocks` to inject my String property? I know I can't mock a String since it's immutable, but can I just inject a normal String here?

`@InjectMocks` injects a null by default in this case. `@Mock` understandably throws an exception if I put it on `myProperty`. Is there another annotation I've missed that just means "inject this exact object rather than a Mock of it"?

Comment: I know I can just manually instantiate my controller in a setup method, but I'm hoping to find a solution the annotation configuration style. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot do this with Mockito, because, as you mentioned yourself, a `String` is `final` and cannot be mocked.

There is a `@Spy` annotation which works on *real* objects, but it has the same limitations as `@Mock`, thus you cannot spy on a `String`.

There is no annotation to tell Mockito to just inject that value without doing any mocking or spying. It would be a good feature, though. Perhaps suggest it at the [Mockito Github repository](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues).

You will have to manually instantiate your controller if you don't want to change your code.

The only way to have a pure annotation based test is to refactor the controller. It can use a custom object that just contains that one property, or perhaps a configuration class with multiple properties.

```
@Component
public class MyProperty {

    @Value("${my.property}")
    private String myProperty;

    ...
}
```

This can be injected into the controller.

```
@Autowired
public AbcController(XyzService xyzService, MyProperty myProperty) { 
    ... 
}
```

You can mock and inject this then.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AbcControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private XyzService mockXyzService;

    @Mock
    private MyProperty myProperty;

    @InjectMocks
    private AbcController controllerUnderTest;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        when(myProperty.get()).thenReturn("my property value");
    }

    /* tests */
}
```

This is not pretty straight forward, but at least you will be able to have a pure annotation based test with a little bit of stubbing.

Comment: That's unfortunate.

I looked through their issue tool, and it looks like they've [discussed](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/174) it [before](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/pull/277). General idea seems to be that it's out-of-scope for a mocking framework, and possibly even a code smell, though I don't think I agree with that.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 52):

You can't do this with Mockito, but Apache Commons actually has a way to do this using one of its built in utilities. You can put this in a function in JUnit that is run after Mockito injects the rest of the mocks but before your test cases run, like this:

```
@InjectMocks
MyClass myClass;

@Before
public void before() throws Exception {
    FieldUtils.writeField(myClass, "fieldName", fieldValue, true);
}
```

Comment: Or you could just use setter method. Any way magic disappears and at this stage even creating MyClass in @Before method is an option :(

Answer (score 30):

Since you're using Spring, you can use the `org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils` from the `spring-test` module. It neatly wraps setting a field on a object or a static field on a class (along with other utility methods).

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AbcControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private XyzService mockXyzService;

    @InjectMocks
    private AbcController controllerUnderTest;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(controllerUnderTest, "myProperty", 
               "String you want to inject");
    }

    /* tests */
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Just don't use @InjectMocks in that case.

do:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
 controllerUnderTest = new AbcController(mockXyzService, "my property value");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution is simple**: You should put constructor injection for the object type while for primitive/final dependencies you can simply use setter injection and that'll be fine for this scenario.

So this:

```
public AbcController(XyzService xyzService, @Value("${my.property}") String myProperty) {/*...*/}
```

Would be changed to:

```
@Autowired
public AbcController(XyzService xyzService) {/*...*/}

@Autowired
public setMyProperty(@Value("${my.property}") String myProperty){/*...*/}
```

And the `@Mock` injections in test would be as simple as:

```
@Mock
private XyzService xyzService;

@InjectMocks
private AbcController abcController;

@BeforeMethod
public void setup(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    abcController.setMyProperty("new property");
}
```

And that'll be enough. Going for `Reflections` is not advisable!

PLEASE AVOID THE USAGE OF REFLECTIONS IN PRODUCTION CODE AS MUCH AS POSSIBLE!!

For the solution of `Jan Groot` I must remind you that it will become very nasty since you will have to remove all the `@Mock` and even `@InjectMocks` and would have to initialize and then inject them manually which for 2 dependencies sound easy but for 7 dependencies the code becomes a nightmare (see below).

```
private XyzService xyzService;
private AbcController abcController;

@BeforeMethod
public void setup(){ // NIGHTMARE WHEN MORE DEPENDENCIES ARE MOCKED!
    xyzService = Mockito.mock(XyzService.class);
    abcController = new AbcController(xyzService, "new property");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can use is this :
**org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.Whitebox**

1. Refactor your "AbcController" class constructor
2. In your Test class "before" method, use Whitebox.setInternalState method to specify whatever string you want

   ```
   @Before
   public void setUp(){
       Whitebox.setInternalState(controllerUnderTest, "myProperty", "The string that you want"); }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have no change in your code then use ReflectionTestUtils.setField method
[How do I mock an autowired @Value field in Spring with Mockito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162777/how-do-i-mock-an-autowired-value-field-in-spring-with-mockito)

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

```
@Autowired
@InjectMocks
private AbcController controllerUnderTest;
```

**Explanation:**
You would be amazed to know how simple but yet tricky it was.
Try to use: **@Autowired** and **@InjectMock** annotations together.

Through this your actual object will be loaded first and then the object which needs to be spied or mocked will be injected. Your actual object will have the values already filled in through the properties.

Comment: How could you possible autowire it in a unit test that doesn't load the app context? If you can do that, then your test is not a unit test!