# Exception: Parameter specified as non-null is null: How to inject field for Mock Test

Tags: kotlin, mockito

I have a service:

```
@Service
class ArchiveService(
        val fnaReactiveClient: FNAReactiveClient,
        val resolvedTopicPrefix: String)
```

And I have Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
class CoreKafkaConfig {
    
    @Value("\${kafka.topicPrefix:}")
    lateinit var topicPrefix: String

    @Bean
    fun resolvedTopicPrefix() = run {
        KafkaTopicsUtil.resolveTopicPrefix(topicPrefix)
    }
```

But in my test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
class ArchiveServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var archiveService: ArchiveService

    @Mock
    lateinit var fnaReactiveClient: FNAReactiveClient

    
 @Test
    fun `create archive with duplicate filenames`() {
        val user = "user"
      
... some when and given block ....

        val newDocVer = archiveService.archiveDoc("integration", null, req, ecmHeaders, EcmServiceAsyncConfig.MethodType.ARCHIVE)
       assertEquals(newId, newDocVer)
       
... some verify block ....
        }
    }
```

I have an exception:

Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'archiveService' of type 'class tu.xxxx.ecm.services.service.ArchiveService'.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : Parameter specified as non-null is null: method tu.xxx.ecm.services.service.ArchiveService., parameter resolvedTopicPrefix

What i am doing wrong????

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you require two arguments to create `ArchiveService`. But... only one mock is defined. **Remember, that while performing unit test, beans are not created and Spring DI injection is not performed.**

So, what you can do. In fact - not a lot.
Please see this thread: [Injecting a String property with @InjectMocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084559/injecting-a-string-property-with-injectmocks)

There are some workarounds, however, the one could argue about readability of such an approach.

So, what I suggest is not using `@InjectMock` in your test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
class ArchiveServiceImplTest {

    lateinit var instance: ArchiveServiceImpl

    @Mock
    lateinit var clientMock: Client

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        instance = ArchiveServiceImpl(clientMock, "fakeId")
    }

    @Test
    fun test() {
        instance.archive("")
    }
}
```