# How to read variable from application.properties from method that is testing

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I have class:

```
@Service
public class A {

  @Value("${a.b.c}")
  private String abc;

  public void foo() {
   sout(abc);
  }
}
```

I Have test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@SpringBootConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.yml")
public class TestA {

  @Value("${a.b.c}")
  private String abc;

  @InjectMocks
  private A a;

  @Test
  public void testFoo() {
    this.a.foo();
  }
}
```

When I debugging the test method `testFoo()`,
I see that variable `abc` is read from the `application.yml` file.
But,
inside the  `foo()` method,
I see that the variable `abc` is null.
How can I set variable `abc` such that it is available in method `foo()` when I trying to test this method?

Comment: Like that: `@SpringBootTest({"a.b.c=myValue"})`

Comment: I tried. Still null

Comment: @AntonKolosok try to replace `@InjectMocks` annotation in the class `TestA` to the `@Autowired`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I mock an autowired @Value field in Spring with Mockito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162777/how-do-i-mock-an-autowired-value-field-in-spring-with-mockito)

Comment: A better solution is to use constructor injection, which will usually let you avoid involving Spring at all and simply do `new A(myTestAbc)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step one is to answer this question: Am I unit testing the code in my class or am I integration testing the combination of Spring and some collection of code that includes my class?

If you are unit testing your code,
then it is not necessary to have Spring do its thing.
Instead,
you only need to instantiate your class,
set the values that Spring would have set for you,
execute the method you are testing,
then verify that your method executed correctly.

Here is your example unit test rewritten as I suggested:

```
public class TestA
{
  private static final String VALUE_ABC = "VALUE_ABC";

  private A classToTest;

  @Test
  public void testFoo()
  {
    classToTest.foo();
  }

  @Before
  public void preTestSetup()
  {
    classToTest = new A();

    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(
      classToTest,
      "abc",
      VALUE_ABC)
  }
}
```

Some Notes:

1. `ReflectionTestUtils` is part of Spring-test.
2. You don't need to use `@InjectMocks` because you have no mocks to inject.
3. I don't know what `sout` is, so I excluded it from the test.  You should verify that the sout method was called with the correct value (in this case VALUE_ABC).
4. If you are just unit testing your code, you don't need Spring, which means that you don't need to use the `@RunWith` annotation.

Comment: Im REALY, REALY thank you. I spend a lot of time to beat it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to overide the properties like that:

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = "location.properties",
  properties = "a.b.c=123")
```

Example taken from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-test-property-source)

Comment: Still have null in foo() method