# Null pointer exception while accessing property from application properties in Junit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, junit4, spring-boot-test

I have method which access property from application.properties & for which I am writing junit.

```
class ServiceClass{

@Value("${urlfromapplicationproperties}")
public String myUrl ;

public String getUrl(){
 return myUrl;
}
}
```

Below is test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringJunit4ClassRunner.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:test:properties")
public class ServiceClassTest {

@Mock 
ServiceClass serviceclass;

@Before
public void setup(){ MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);}

@Test
public myTestMethod(){

serviceclass.getUrl();
}
}
```

when I access the method its throwing null pointer. I have declared that property in application-test.yml too. what I am missing? any reference or answer to resolve this?

Comment: this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162777/how-do-i-mock-an-autowired-value-field-in-spring-with-mockito

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ReflectionTestUtils` [setField](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html#setField-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)

```
@Before
public void setup(){
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(serviceclass, "myUrl", "http://testurl");
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ServiceClass should be define as Spring bean

```
@Configuration    
public class ServiceClass {
```