# Spring boot custom properties for junit test

Tags: java, spring, junit

Here is the class that gets its pathToFile from application.properties.

```
@Component
public class CSVReader {

    @Value("${name.basics}")
    private String pathToFile;

   (other code)
}
```

The problem is: how can I substitute application.properties for testing?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-tests-override-properties

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I mock an autowired @Value field in Spring with Mockito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162777/how-do-i-mock-an-autowired-value-field-in-spring-with-mockito)

Answer (score 1):

You can use spring boot test annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"name.basics=whatever"})
public class YourTestClass {

@Autowired 
CSVReader cvsReader;

@Test
public void yourTest() {
//...
```

Second option is to put `application-test.properties` containing replacements in `src/test/resources` folder of your project