# How to Mock Map when using @Value using Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I already went through this question: [How do I mock an autowired @Value field in Spring with Mockito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162777/how-do-i-mock-an-autowired-value-field-in-spring-with-mockito). How can we mock the following?

```
@Value("#{${patientTypes}}")
private Map<String, Integer> patientTypes;
```

So that we can access its value when doing mocking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to mock your map and inject it in your class under test, you should just create a mock map and inject it via `ReflectionTestUtils`:

Class under test:

```
@Component
public class MyService {

    @Value("#{${patientTypes}}")
    private Map<String, Integer> patientTypes;

    public Integer getPatientTypeByKey(String key) {
        return patientTypes.get(key);
    }
}
```

For Mockito-test you can use just `InjectMocks`:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class SimpleTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private MyService underTest;

    @Mock
    private Map<String, Integer> mockMap;


    @Test
    public void test() {
        when(mockMap.get(anyString())).thenReturn(15);

        Integer result = underTest.getPatientTypeByKey("some key");

        assertEquals(15, result);
    }
}
```

For SpringBootTest `ReflectionTestUtils` can be used:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class SBTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService underTest;

    @Mock
    private Map<String, Integer> mockMap;


    @Test
    public void test() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(underTest, "patientTypes", mockMap);

        when(mockMap.get(anyString())).thenReturn(15);

        Integer result = underTest.getPatientTypeByKey("some key");

        assertEquals(15, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks, but this is not working for me `ReflectionTestUtils.setField(underTest, "patientTypes", mockMap);`