# Springboot & Mockito - Using ReflectionTestUtils.setField calling method twice

Tags: spring-boot, reflection, mockito, junit5, spring-boot-test

I want to inject value to a private field annotated with @Value in my Junit5 unit test.

```
@Value("$(invoice.maxRetry)")
private maxRetry;
```

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162777/how-do-i-mock-an-autowired-value-field-in-spring-with-mockito) and used ReflectionTestUtils.setField which solved my problem by injecting a value but failed when verifying the no. of times the method get called.

MyClass:

```
    public class MessageProcessor {
         
    @Value("$(invoice.maxRetry)")
        private maxRetry;
    
    protected void handleMessage() {
            if(retry > maxRetry) {
                kafkaTemplate.sendMessage(msg);
       }
}
```

TestClass:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MessageProcessorTest {

@Mock
private kafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate;

@Mock
private MessageProcessor messageProcessor

@Test
test() {
     ReflectionTestUtils.setField(messageProcessor, "maxRetry", "5");
     doNothing().when(kafkaTemplate).sendMessage(any());
     messageProcessor.handleMessage();
     verify(kafkaTemplate).sendMessage(any());
  }
}
```

Error running above test

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
kafkaTemplate.sendMessage(<any>);
Wanted 1 time:
But was 2
```

I want *kafkaTemplate.sendMessage();* to be called only once but getting called twice after adding ReflectionTestUtils.

Need advice on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the usage of `ReflectionTestUtils` by slightly refactoring your class and favoring construct injection:

```
public class MessageProcessor {
     
    private String maxRetry;
    private KafkaTemplate template;

    // ... any further fields

    public class MessageProcessor(@Value("$(invoice.maxRetry)") String maxRetry, KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate) {
       this.maxRetry = maxRetry;
       this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    }

 }
```

Within your test you can then control the value of `maxRetry` by creating an instance of your class under test (`MessageProcessor`) manually.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public MessageProcessorTest {

  @Mock 
  private KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate;

  private MessageProcessor messageProcessor;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    this.messageProcessor = new MessageProcessor("42", kafkaTemplate);

  }

}
```

... and then only rely on JUnit and Mocktio which should help you add the verification.